# Typescipt string literals as generics: Exhausiveness check in switch

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, typescript-generics, string-literals

I have the following oversimplified code snippet:

```js
type a = 'a' | 'b';
const fn = <T extends a>(param: T): T => {
  switch(param) {
    case 'a':
      return 'a' as T;
    case 'b':
      return 'b' as T;
  }
};
```

I cannot figure out, why does the compiler complain about the lack of return, and is there a way to fix it that is future proof (e.g. not adding a default case, I wanna make sure all cases are explicitly handled, so if in the future the type is extended, I do want it to fail)

it works when I remove the generic, but in my scenario, the return type is generic on T

Comment: It's a missing feature; generics don't participate in control flow analysis the same way as non-generics, see [ms/TS#13215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13215). Since you have to write `as T` anyway you might as well give up on narrowing a generic in the first place, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WGGo2W). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the playground link, it solve the above simple case, and one of my issues (please post the playground as an answer, and Ill accept). I have a [more complex scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77919237/typescipt-string-literals-as-generics-with-dependent-type-exhausiveness-check-i) though, where that is not enough, any ideas for that too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a missing feature of TypeScript, reported at [microsoft/TypeScript#13215](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13215).  [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) don't work together very well; if you want to get [exhaustiveness checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#exhaustiveness-checking) from `switch`/`case` statements, then you'll need the relevant value to be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) directly and not a generic type [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union.  Maybe someday TypeScript will automatically apply exhaustiveness checks for generics, but for now it's not part of the language.

---

For the example code as given, the simplest approach is to widen `param` from `T` to `"a" | "b"` when doing the check:

```
type AB = 'a' | 'b';
const fn = <T extends AB>(param: T): T => { // okay
  const p: AB = param; // <-- widen
  switch (p) {
    case 'a':
      return 'a' as T;
    case 'b':
      return 'b' as T;
  }
};
```

You could also use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) with a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to safely widen a value without copying it to a new variable.  That is, `x satisfies Y as Y` will only compile if `x` is assignable to `Y` (the `satisfies` check) and the whole expression will be treated as type `Y` (the `as` assertion):

to provide context that `param` should be

```
const fn = <T extends AB>(param: T): T => { // okay
  switch (param satisfies AB as AB) {
    case 'a':
      return 'a' as T;
    case 'b':
      return 'b' as T;
  }
};
```

These approaches, of course, lose the generic behavior, so neither `"a"` nor `"b"` will be seen as assignable to the generic type parameter `T`. That means you still need to use the type assertions in `return "a" as T` and `return "b" as T`.  There are often ways to refactor code to maintain the generic behavior, but they will necessarily not use a `switch`/`case` statement and are therefore out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=false&ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA5AQxVAPqgRigbgCgBjAewDsBnYKAMwqSgB4AVKCAD2AgoBMqsOAD4AFGDQAnNAFsAXFFYBKBe0TCoAbygB6HVDIBrNCCJQo5arTAL4TCdJkFd+5gFo3UAO4BLPrzMoKl9gEgALKHElLUDzEjQqaHQUOVjzKEkIYABXSUZkqATFYnSLBKT8VNLzTJy8vEwi1hKoAF8iVuJSShp6CgAmJjYObl4BITEHWVUVRSQNbT0DY1NzYJ9QiPEpWSC0YB8qOh8IQTsi+GjNNPjE1Awq6trc-IxCwWab8obH0uf6lD4d7FQLtTpEIA)