# Typescipt string literals as generics with dependent type: Exhausiveness check in switch

Tags: typescript, switch-statement, typescript-generics, string-literals

As a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77917345/typescipt-string-literals-as-generics-exhausiveness-check-in-switch)

I have the following code snippet:

```js
const operations = {
   DDB: ["getItem"] as const;
   S3: ["putObject"] as const;
}
type service = keyof typeof operations;
type serviceOperation<T extends service> = typeof operation[T][number]
type resourceFor<T extends service> = T extends 'S3' ? Bucket : T extends 'DDB' : Table : never;

const setPermission = <T extends service>(serviceType: T, operation: serviceOperation<T>): ((caller: LambdaFunction, resource: ResourceFor<T>) => void) => {
  switch(serviceType) {
    case 'DDB':
        switch(operation) {
            case 'getItem': return (lambda: LambdaFunction, table: Table) => table.grandReadData(lambda);
        }
    case 'S3':
        switch(operation) {
            case 'putObject': return (lambda: LambdaFunction, bucket: Bucket) => bucket.grandWrite(lambda);
        }
  }
};
```

This has 2 issues:

1. I need to cast the return statements to the `as ((caller: LambdaFunction, resource: ResourceFor<T>) => void)`. It is not nice, but I can live with that.
2. with the casts, it fails with `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`

[The suggestion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?pretty=false&ts=5.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvFA5AQxVAPqgRigbgCgBjAewDsBnYKAMwqSgB4AVKCAD2AgoBMqsOAD4AFGDQAnNAFsAXFFYBKBe0TCoAbygB6HVDIBrNCCJQo5arTAL4TCdJkFd+5gFo3UAO4BLPrzMoKl9gEgALKHElLUDzEjQqaHQUOVjzKEkIYABXSUZkqATFYnSLBKT8VNLzTJy8vEwi1hKoAF8iVuIgA) in the original question does not solve this case unfortunately

Comment: This code is not a [mre]; it contains typos and undeclared/private/third-party types and values. Could you fix that by trying out your code in a standalone IDE and making sure that the only issues present are the ones you're asking about?  That will make it easier for others to get to work on it.  While you're at it, please consider adhering to TS naming conventions; types are conventionally written in `UpperCamelCase` to distinguish them from `lowerCamelCase` values.